# ConstraintLayout performance - Guidelines vs Margins

Tags: android, performance, android-constraintlayout

I'm using **ConstraintLayout** in most of my layouts, and I want to know what's the best practice in the performance aspect:

1. Using a guideline as a view's limit, including as a margin limit.

**Example**: 4 `guidelines` in total, no `margins`.

[guideline picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCZqC.jpg)

2. Using a view margin, which will result in less accurate spacing, because I will need to insert an arbitrary number of dps.

**example:** 2 `guidelines` in total, 2 `margins (top + bottom)`

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

[margins picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNgxN.jpg)

If you have another option, I will be happy to read it.
Also, I would like to know how to track performance of layout configuration such as this (where have you looked / what have you used to give me the answer).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can get the same result without guidelines. Percent dimensions can be used in ConstraintLayout.

Just set the "layout_constraintHeight_default" attribute to "percent" (to use percentage units), and set the percentage using "layout_constraintHeight_percent". (width related attributes are available too)

As for the layout performance between 4 widgets, and, 2 widgets and 2 constraints(margins). I am sure that the latter will do better as it takes a smaller layout to render.
However, in this case, the difference is insignificant.

Comment: You are right "difference is insignificant" so I have chosen to use a keyboard layout as part of figuring out the best performance practices for constraintLayouts see-> https://stackoverflow.com/q/52847213/1815624